# How to get a sublist in a list in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am wondering get a sublist in a list,like:

```
user=> (findsublst '(hello world (10 clock)))
(10 clock)
```

what function can I use or how to define the functioin findsublst. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any criteria for the sublist? In your example `last` would do the trick.

Comment: The sublist can be anywhere in the list. Like, '(the (2 big) boat), ((1 this) is (2 very) nice)), ((3 oh) wow).@ChrisMurphy

Comment: If you need to do a lot of slicing, a vector is probably a better data type for that because it supports [`subvec`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/subvec).  Can you work with vectors here?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the suggested question, as discussed in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439643/how-to-get-a-sublist-in-a-list-in-clojure#comment58577774_35439965)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With very little to go on, the following will return all first level list/sequences contained by the primary:

```
(filter seq? '(1 2 3 (4 5 6)))
=> ((4 5 6))
```

Comment: That is indeed what I about to post (except that I added `first`).  I think the confusion here comes from the OP's use of the term "sublist", which means "a portion of a list" rather than a list nested in a list, which is what he actually meant.

Comment: @z7sgѪ Yes, I was going to add `first` but it was ambiguous if there would potentially be multiple nested lists.

Comment: Thank you all! I want to get all the sublists in the list. So I do not need to use `first` here. You guys help me to clear my confusion!